# Unable to login user accounts I have created in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, flush

I can login to my site with a superuser but the accounts I have created get the invalid login page. I am using the django authentication system, not my own.

Before this happened I made a mistake by deleting one of the fields in one of my models to fix something (no idea why I thought that would help). I flushed the database and added the field again to fix that.

After flushing I was getting an error when I tried to migrate that I had a duplicate column. Running `python manage.py migrate --fake` fixed that problem.

I created a few new users to test with in the admin site but when I tried to log in with them it didn't work.

Any ideas?

The model I changed

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField()
    catagoryID = models.ForeignKey(Catagory)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    userEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    resolved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    dateOfIssue = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The field I removed was the user field. 
I'll post more code if necessary.

Comment: Can you tell how you flushed the database?

Comment: I used "python manage.py flush"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I managed to get around this by only using users with encrypted passwords. That is why my admin could sign in but not any users I had made in the admin site.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help you, but check whether the created user is active. It could also be a problem with the cookie not being set properly as mentioned in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/admin/#i-can-t-log-in-when-i-enter-a-valid-username-and-password-it-just-brings-up-the-login-page-again-with-no-error-messages)

> The login cookie isn’t being set correctly, because the domain of the cookie sent out by Django doesn’t match the domain in your browser. Try these two things:
>
> Set the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN setting in your admin config file to match your domain. For example, if you’re going to “http://www.example.com/admin/” in your browser, in “myproject.settings” you should set SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ‘www.example.com’.

Comment: There was no sign of SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN in my settings.py so I added it in. Still not working though. In fact it wouldn't led my superuser login either!